# ListView : is onContentChanged complete

Tags: android, android-listview, android-loadermanager

I'm building a ListView using a custom ListFragment that implements the LoaderManager, a custom ArrayAdapter and a custom AsyncTaskLoader.
What i'm trying to do is loading the ListView from a database table (that works). If I have a SharedPreference, I add a row in the database, then ask the ListView to be updated through a Broadcast receiver (that works), and finaly edit the ListView to hide a TextView and show an EditText (which doesn't works).
When I'm trying to access to the particular row in the method

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Favoris>> loader, List<Favoris> data)
```

I have a nullPointer exception. I guess that the problem is that the method onContentChanged() is not finished, and the ListView ain't fully updated.
Do you have any idea on where I should move the last part of my code ? (instead of putting it in onLoadFinished)

EDIT :

```
public static class FavListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Favoris>> {
  private static final String TAG = "ADP_AppListFragment";
  private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

  // We use a custom ArrayAdapter to bind application info to the ListView.
  private FavoritesListAdapter mAdapter;

  // The Loader's id (this id is specific to the ListFragment's LoaderManager)
  private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);

    mAdapter = new FavoritesListAdapter(getActivity());
    setEmptyText("No applications");
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    setListShown(false);

    if (DEBUG) {
      Log.i(TAG, "+++ Calling initLoader()! +++");
      if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ Initializing the new Loader... +++");
      } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "+++ Reconnecting with existing Loader (id '1')... +++");
      }
    }

    // Initialize a Loader with id '1'. If the Loader with this id already
    // exists, then the LoaderManager will reuse the existing Loader.
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
  }

  /**********************/
  /** LOADER CALLBACKS **/
  /**********************/

  @Override
  public Loader<List<Favoris>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ onCreateLoader() called! +++");
    return new FavorisListLoader(getActivity());
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Favoris>> loader, List<Favoris> data) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ onLoadFinished() called! +++");
    mAdapter.setData(data);

    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ setData() called! +++");

    if (isResumed()) {
      setListShown(true);
    } else {
      setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }


    //addedFav is the favorite item added in the DataBase
    if(addedFav != null) {

        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ Favoris added : "  + addedFav.getAddress() + " | " + addedFav.getAddressAliasName() );

        int addedFavPos = mAdapter.getPosition(addedFav);

        ListView favListView = this.getListView();

        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ Listing Item : "  + favListView.toString() );

        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ ListView Favoris position : "  + addedFavPos );

        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ ListView Favoris count : " + favListView.getCount() + " +++");

        View vFavoris = this.getListView().getChildAt(addedFavPos);

        TextView favoriteAliasAddressNameTextView = (TextView) vFavoris.findViewById(R.id.addressAliasName);
        favoriteAliasAddressNameTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        EditText favoriteAliasAddressNameEditText = (EditText) vFavoris.findViewById(R.id.addressAliasName_editText);
        favoriteAliasAddressNameEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ editText should be shown ! +++");

    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ onLoadFinished() FINISHED! +++");
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Favoris>> loader) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "+++ onLoadReset() called! +++");
    mAdapter.setData(null);
  }
```

}

Comment: You should post the code "to access the particular row".

Comment: Keep in mind that `getChildAt()` can be used with indexes starting from `0` to `getChildCount()`, so your `addedFavPos` must be offset to be inside that interval(which I assume, you're not doing).

Comment: Actually, addedFav is a Favoris Object. When i add a favorite in the database it returns me a favoris Object, then i use SendBroadcast to call onContentChange() in the right place, and finally look for the position of the Favoris Object in my ListView.
I added a loop in onLoadFinished() function printing each this.getListView().getChildAt(i), and it returns null for each (but this.getListView().getCount() returns the right number).

I assume that the ListView hasn't finished to be fill by Favorite. So I'm wondering where to is it supposed to be ...

Comment: PS : addedFavPos equals -1, which means it's not in the List<Favoris> of the Adapter ... If i remove the piece of code, i do have the ListView with the favorite row added in

Comment: I guess that onLoadFinished() is not the place where ListView is done populating ...